The canny edge detector output image is black (all zeros)
This is my code in Python (google colab). I have an ultrasound image, and I am trying to get the white spots.
#Pixel values
print("Value of pixel max",np.max(I1))
print("Value of pixel min",np.min(I1))

array = np.array(I1)

I1 = I1.astype('float32')
print(I1.shape)
low_threshold=np.max(I1) 
high_threshold=np.max(I1)
edges = cv.Canny(np.uint8(I1), 0.3, 0.9)
print("Value of edges pixel max",np.max(edges))
print("Value of edges pixel min",np.min(edges))
showimage(edges)
plt.show()


def showimage(I):
    plt.imshow(I, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.axis('off')
showimage(I)
plt.show()

The answer is:
Value of pixel max 0.91376376
Value of pixel min 0.037596334
(173, 120, 1)
Value of edges pixel max 0
Value of edges pixel min 0
I tried adding np.uint8() to the image, and also I1 = I1.astype('float32'). I am expecting that the result does not give all zeros.
